# Creating a Jar for a Automation project Java+Gradle+Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, automation

Ihave a gradle project that has an automated test cases for a web application using selenium. All the tests and test cases are with in the package src/test/java. The tear down scripts (to clean up the entries in DB are written in src/main/java after test case execution). I tried to build a JAR using gradle for the same. I could get 2 different JAR's one that contains just the classes under src/main/java and the other containing src/test/java. Is there a way to build a single JAR that contains both? Let me know if there is an alternate way of doing the same.

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    testJar.execute()
}

Thank you!
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @lu.koerfer please find attached.

Comment: Do you use the `java` plugin? If yes, just add the test sources to the normal jar task via `jar { from sourceSets.test.output }`. Please **NEVER** use `execute()` on tasks. It is not part of the public API and using it may break Gradle!!!

Comment: sure.. will try the same and let you knwo